# links in toggled nested list not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm totally stuck and tried several days to solve my problem.
Below you see the html-structure I'm working with.
I'm inserting the nested list via JS.
My problem is that I want to display Link1a and Link1b like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jBMr/).
As you can see here the text of the last div is overwritten by the nested list.

But in my case on the site I'm trying to manipulate the links are not clickable.
I guess I'm missing an attribute, but can't figure out which one.

Can you help me?

```
<div id="main">
  <ul>
    <li style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 0px;">
      <a href="link1">Link1</a>
    </li>
    <li style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 0px;">
      <a href="#">Disabled link</a>
      <ul style="position: absolute; margin-top: 5px;" class="tohover">
         <li>
            <a href="#">Link1a</a>
         </li>
         <li>
           <a href="#">Link1b</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#main > ul > li").css({'display':'inline-block','vertical-align':'top','padding':'0px'});

  $("<ul class='tohover' style='display:none;'>
      <li><a href='#'>Link 1a</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Link 1a</a></li>
      </ul>").insertAfter("#main a[href$='link1']");

  $("#main a[href$='link1']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".tohover").toggle().css("position","absolute").css("margin-top","5px");
  });

});
```

Comment: Just to verify, you want the Link1a and Link1b to disable upon clicking the Disable link, is this correct?

Comment: Yer, well. Link1a and Link1b are only shown when I click on the Disabled link. They're toogled. But when I first click on Disabled link, they're shown but do not have any functionality which I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is a problem with `z-index` just try to set: `<ul class='tohover' style='display:none; z-index: 999;'>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `event.preventDefault();`

Example:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Hi, I'm already using this function to disable the Disabled link to toggle Link1a and Link1b. But those two links do not have the functionality of links. I cannot click them.